# Call javascript function in twig after if constraint is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, twig

How can I call javascript function it twig that is localized in 
`<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>` if constraint is fulfilled in twig.
for example:

`{% if app.user %}
 call javascriptfunction here 
 {% else %}
 {% endif %}`

Comment: Presumably Twig is a template engine, so you can't just call js from it. What you can do is conditionally output some html, inside of which you can have a script tag where you can call the js.

Comment: What kind of javascript function you are using. Is it returning any value or just validation? I am not aware of syntax of twig engine. But, i think, you could try like <script> javascript function </script> . I am not sure , mate.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I would do this.  Firstly, if you only want to call your JS function from the Twig file, you've basically already got it.

Define your function in main.js.  Then as you've already got, in the Twig file:

```
{% if app.user %}
    <script>
        doFunction();
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Secondly, if it's a function that always executes, and you want some logic in there that relies on the variable that Twig uses, do something like this.

In the HTML in your Twig file, as Hunan suggests, add something that indicates the value of `app.user`.  e.g.

```
<div id="yourUser" data-app-user="{{ app.user }}">
```

Then in your function, use some JS to check for this value being set, e.g. (I'm assuming you're using jQuery):

```
function checkUser() {
    if ($('#yourUser').data('appUser')) {
        // do something specific for the user
    } else {
        // or do something else...
    }
}
```